# LiveScript's "require 'mymodule'" is not working in browser

Tags: node.js, browserify, livescript

I need to modularize my LiveScript project just like [prelude-ls](https://github.com/gkz/prelude-ls) project does.

Here is my [test project](https://bitbucket.org/ceremcem/livescript-module-test):

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/ceremcem/livescript-module-test
```

In the [Readme.md](https://bitbucket.org/ceremcem/livescript-module-test/src/d8145bbff1dc6075bc18e5b1ab4b81cb28a850ec/Readme.md?at=master) I included the steps to reproduce the problem:

Run server code:

```
  $ lsc server.ls
```

You will see the proper output.

Run client code:

```
  $ lsc -c myapp.ls
  $ lsc -c mymodule.ls
  $ browserify -r ./mymodule.js > mymodule-browser.js
  $ firefox index.html
```

Open firebug, you will see the error:

```
  Error: Cannot find module './mymodule'

  ...eturn a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");...
```

Comment: Try `browserify -t browserify-livescript -r ./mymodule.ls`?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work either. I edited my question to include the test project's source code. Maybe you want to take a look at it.

Comment: It's solvet with the `-r` option but in a strange way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After examining prelude-ls project a bit deeper and with the helps of [loganfsmyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785065/loganfsmyth), here is [the example code](https://bitbucket.org/ceremcem/livescript-module-test) and [here is the recipe] to build a browser version of a module:

> Run server code:
>
> ```
> $ lsc server.ls
> ```
>
> You will see the proper output:
>
> ```
> this is server script, running with lsc
> my test function has been called
> ```
>
> Run client code:
>
> ```
> $ lsc -c myapp.ls
> $ lsc -c mymodule.ls
> $ browserify -r ./mymodule.js:mymodule > mymodule-browser.js
> $ firefox index.html
> ```
>
> Open firebug, you will see the proper output:
>
> ```
> my app is running
> my test function has been called
> ```

Comment: It needs to be in that folder if there is no `./` in the argument, but it should (in theory) work without that if you do `./mymodule`

Comment: Yes, you were right. I corrected the code, it's in the repo. Thank you.